# The FK relationship was not loaded because the type is not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll

In one of our C# batch jobs, we use a dll that was built using the Entity Framewok 4.1. The batch job, however, also uses the EF (same version) and it looks like this might be causing some trouble.

In both the dll and batch job's `.edmx` files is a relationship between the `AgentTransmission` and `AgentRelationshipCodes` table. `AgentTransmission` has a one-to-many relationship with `AgentRelationshipCodes`. The PK of `AgentTransmission` serves as a FK field on the `AgentRelationshipCodes` table.

The section of code below is from a routine in the dll. This method is called by the batch job to look for any record on the `AgentTransmission` table with a status of `Waiting` (or `W`).

```
namespace Botticelli
{
    public class MonetToMainframe : IMonetToMainframe
    {
        private static TransmitAgents _db;

        public ResponseMessage TransmitWaitingAgents()
        {
            try
            {
                _db = new TransmitAgents();

                //Exception thrown here
                agtTran = _db.AgentTransmission.FirstOrDefault(w => w.RecordStatus.Equals("W"));
```

When the last line above is run it hits the following exception

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

The relationship 'MonetModel.FK__AgentRela__AgtTa__3449B6E4' was not loaded because the 
type 'MonetModel.AgentRelationshipCode' is not available.
```

I've seen this error message in a number of posts on the net but haven't been able to find a solution. At the moment I'm just stuck looking for even a direction to search in.

This first thing that jumps out at me, however, is that the message is referencing `MonetModel` as the namespace of the FK relationship. The `MonetModel` namespace is used the the EF `DbContext` that is used strictly in the batch job. The `DbContext` class `TransmitAgents`, however belongs to the `Botticelli` namespace which is used in the dll.

As you can see from the screen shot below, however, this FK relationship is defined in both namespaces (one used by the batch job, one by the dll)

[image]

For good measure here are the relevant classes/fields pulled from both the dll and batch job EF namespaces

**DLL - AgentTransmission**

```
namespace Botticelli
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AgentTransmission
    {
        public AgentTransmission()
        {
            this.AgentRelationshipCodes = new HashSet<AgentRelationshipCodes>();
        }

        //Tons of fields here, edited for readability

        public virtual ICollection<AgentRelationshipCodes> AgentRelationshipCodes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DLL - AgentRelationshipCodes**

```
namespace Botticelli
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AgentRelationshipCodes
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string LastChangeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AgtTableId { get; set; }

        public virtual AgentTransmission AgentTransmission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DLL - DbContext**

```
namespace Botticelli
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class TransmitAgents : DbContext
    {
        public TransmitAgents()
            : base("name=TransmitAgents")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<TransmissionHistory> TransmissionHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentRelationshipCodes> AgentRelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentTransmission> AgentTransmission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Batch Job - AgentTransmission**

```
namespace LVOAGT
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AgentTransmission
    {
        public AgentTransmission()
        {
            this.AgentRelationshipCodes = new HashSet<AgentRelationshipCode>();
        }

        //Tons of fields here, edited for readability

        public virtual ICollection<AgentRelationshipCode> AgentRelationshipCodes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Batch Job - AgentRelationshipCodes**

```
namespace LVOAGT
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AgentRelationshipCode
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string LastChangeId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AgtTableId { get; set; }

        public virtual AgentTransmission AgentTransmission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Batch Job - DbContext**

```
namespace LVOAGT
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MonetDb : DbContext
    {
        public MonetDb()
            : base("name=MonetDb")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<BatchDashboard> BatchDashboard { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransmissionHistory> TransmissionHistories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ConfigStuff> ConfigStuffs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentRelationshipCode> AgentRelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentTransmission> AgentTransmissions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the edmx file in all projects?

Comment: Yeah, dropped/added both tables in both edmx files. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I created new table “post” and gave foreign key relation to another “category” table after that run the custom tool by right click on edmx file. While running the application I got the following error. It was resolved by including post table foreign key relation to the category class.

```
 public Category()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();

    }
 public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

I have included in category model class.for more details:
http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/-Solved-The-relationship-model-was-not-loaded-because-the-type-model-is-not-available/1244

Answer (score 1):

This was occuring because the "pluralization" option was set when I added the tables to the .edmx. This resulted in Class names like so:

**DLL**

```
namespace Botticelli
{
    public partial class AgentRelationshipCodes
    {
```

**Batch Job**

```
namespace LVOAGT
{
    public partial class AgentRelationshipCode
    {
```

Simply made the names uniform and problem solved.